# How can i implement popup login form with ajaxvalidation in YII?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, yii

I have my yii login form `ajaxvalidation` works perfectly in normal mode, But it didn't works on popup mode, i used

`$this->renderPartial('login',array('model'=>$model));` instead of `$this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));` .

I think the problem is with the render partial,it not loads the necessary java scripts for ajax validation. How can i implement popup login form with ajaxvalidation?

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors? Perhaps you should load the javascript files in the main view, not in the popup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cant say without seeing  the entire view file. Anyway try the following code to load the javascripts on `renderPartial`

```
$this->renderPartial('login',array('model'=>$model),false,true);
```

Comment: it works when we put the below line before renderpartial call you sugested, anyway thanks, it helpd :) 'Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap=array('jquery.js'=>false,);'